# Build order in maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am a novice in Maven and hence struggling to impose order of build in my maven project.

I have four steps in my java project which needs to be executed in order.

1. Here I use a maven plugin to generate some code automatically
2. Using the generated code in step1, run a class and create a file under /src/main/resources
3. Using the file created in 2 above, another maven plugin need to run and generate few more automated code classes
4. Using the classes generated in 3, run the final class

Wondering what is the best approach to solve this problem in Maven.

Thanks

Comment: you may need to use multiple modules

Comment: Multiple modules don't help here. That would produce multiple jars. This is more complicated than that. In fact, this is quite difficult in maven.

Comment: First of all, a build should never generate elements in the `src` directory, only in `target`. That said, I guess you can attach your four steps to four consecutive phases of the Maven lifecycle. But let me remark that I wonder whether this really has to be this complicated. Maybe, if you explain in more detail what you are doing, we'll find an easier and more direct solution for you.